# prevent form from executing if field is blank

Tags: php, jquery

i am trying to prevent the form from executing if the search field is blank.

html

```
<form id="form" action="">
<input type="text" id="lookup"><input type="submit" id="find" value="Look Up">

</form>
```

jquery

```
$('#find').click(function(){
var s = ('#lookup').attr('value');
if(s!=""){
$.ajax({
url: result/,
type:'POST',
data: s
success: function(){ //empty }
});
}
});
```

also tried

```
action="result" //form the form

$('#find').click(function(){
var s = ('#lookup').attr('value');
if(s!=""){
$("#form").submit();
}
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can simple add do this

```
$('#find').click(function(){ 
var s = ('#lookup').attr('value'); 
if(s==""){ 
return false; 
} 
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Bind the [`submit`](http://api.jquery.com/submit/) event, and return `false` when the search field is blank, and `true` if it isn't. Returning `false` will prevent the form from being submitted.

```
$("form").submit(function() {
    var s = $.trim($('#lookup').val());
    if (s) {
        $.ajax();
        return true;
    }
    return false;
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/wAhQs/)**.

Answer (score 1):

```
     $('#find').click(function(e){
    var s = ('#lookup').attr('value');
    if(s!=""){
    $.ajax({
    url: result/,
    type:'POST',
    data: s
    success: function(){ //empty }
    });
    } 
      e.preventDefault();
    });
```

e.preventDefault() will stop submit button from actually submitting a form.  Or you can use return false.

But suppose in your case it will be enough to do something like:

```
    $('#find').click(function(e){
var s = ('#lookup').attr('value');
if(s==""){
    e.preventDefault();
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$('#find').click(function(){
    var s = ('#lookup').val();
    if(s!="" && s != undefined && s!=null){
       //do your business here
    }
});
```